# How to make a redirect including the name of the project in the url in Spring MVC?

Tags: java, spring-mvc

I'm new to spring, but not in the world of frameworks. What I have noticed is that the addresses are handled with the name of the project, and then the specified routes.

What happens is that when I am trying to call a controller action from a view, I do the following:

```
<td class="cell1"><span style="color:#696969;font-family:Arial;font-size:15px;line-height:16px;"><a href="/user/${usuario.cedula}/delete">Eliminar</a></span></td>
```

Therefore, the controller is as follows:

```
@PostMapping("/{idUser}/delete")
    public String deleteUser(@PathVariable (value = "idUser") Integer cedula, Model model){
        Usuario usuario = this.usuarioService.find(cedula);
        usuario.setEstaOculto(true);

        this.usuarioService.update(usuario);
        model.addAttribute("mensaje", "Usuario eliminado correctamente");
        return "redirect:/user/";
    }
```

Sure, and the following should happen:

```
http://localhost:8084/trabajaya/user/423423/delete
```

But the redirection is bad for me, since it "eats" the name "trabajaya", which is the name of the project, and leaves it as follows.

```
http://localhost:8084/user/423423/delete
```

Of course, the ideal is to name the gasdfvgsdfd subpath to the part of the html that requires it, but it is not ideal, since I am working on AWS and in this it changes the name of the project.

In case it is enecsario, I leave the configuration of the routes and the resources, although I don't think it helps a lot

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
//BUSQUEDA DE TODAS LAS CLASES Y PAQUETES DERIVADOS DE com.howtodoinjava.demo.spring
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"edu.co.ucatolica.trabajaya"})
@EnableJpaRepositories
@Import(HibernateConfig.class)
public class WebMvcConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {

    @Bean
    public InternalResourceViewResolver resolver() {
        InternalResourceViewResolver resolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
        resolver.setViewClass(JstlView.class);
        //AQUI BUSCA LAS VISTAS
        resolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/views/");
        resolver.setSuffix(".jsp");
        return resolver;
    }

    @Bean
    public MessageSource messageSource() {
        ResourceBundleMessageSource source = new ResourceBundleMessageSource();
        source.setBasename("messages");
        return source;
    }

    @Override
    public Validator getValidator() {
        LocalValidatorFactoryBean validator = new LocalValidatorFactoryBean();
        validator.setValidationMessageSource(messageSource());
        return validator;
    }

    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addResourceHandler("/resources/**").addResourceLocations("/WEB-INF/resources/");
    }
}
```

How do I correct this?

Thank you.

Comment: try this `<a href="user/${usuario.cedula}/delete">Eliminar</a>` ..... just remove first `/` from href

Answer (score 0):

I was really drowning in a glass of water, it is pure basic HTML, I have not used HTML for a while and I had forgotten how to use it.

Simply by adding the following:

```
<td class="cell1"><span style="color:#696969;font-family:Arial;font-size:15px;line-height:16px;"><a href="${usuario.cedula}/delete">Eliminar</a></span></td>
```

OR:

```
<td class="cell1"><span style="color:#696969;font-family:Arial;font-size:15px;line-height:16px;"><a href="user/${usuario.cedula}/delete">Eliminar</a></span></td>
```

It is already corrected and redirected to the corresponding route and the controller answers the call.

Now, if you want to redirect a link to another controller it is as follows:

```
<td class="cell1"><span style="color:#696969;font-family:Arial;font-size:15px;line-height:16px;"><a href="../othercontroller/${usuario.cedula}/update">Modificar</a></span></td>
```

Thanks from @Istiaque Hossain for his answer